# Cosets and normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm super confused on the following problem:

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that the sets $(G/H)_{l}$ and $(G/H)_{r}$ are equal. Does $H$ have to be a normal subgroup of $G$? Justify your answer through a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this question is asking is to show this:

If the following sets are equal:

$$\{xH \mathrel | x \in G \} =
\{Hx \mathrel | x \in G\}$$

Then is $H$ a normal subgroup?

The answer is "yes"!

Details: (from [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_is_Normal_iff_Left_Cosets_are_Right_Cosets))

Say $Hx$ is a right coset of $H$. Then we know there
exists a $y \in G$ such that

$$Hx = yH$$

Then we know that $x \in yH$, so $y^{-1}x \in H$.

Then

$$
\begin{split}
Hx &= yH \\
   &= y (y^{-1} x)H \\
   &= xH
\end{split}
$$

So $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking it was something along those lines!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any $ a \in G $, $ aH \cap Ha $ is always nonempty for any subgroup $ H $.